# Точка, поставленная при прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь

Как я понимаю, эта точка нужна, так как она относится ко вторым, а не первым кавычкам. Так?

> Я был в ярости, когда папа сказал: «Слушай маму, даже когда она говорит: „Мне решать, с кем тебе можно встречаться, а с кем — ни за что!“»(.)

Comment: Стилистика нехороша. Это предложение (два двоеточия) сложно прочитать как нечто целое. Оно будет распадаться на отдельные части. Нет единства.